# How to disable "Use debug .dcus" in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, debugging, c++builder

My debugger steps through Delphi's VCL code when I press F7.
Under the Delphi compiler I need to disable "Use debug .dcus" (I have it off).
How is that option called under C++ Builder?

Comment: It is the same option. There is only 1 set of debug binaries for both compilers.

Comment: ok. that makes it clear now. thanks. if you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Compiling

Project > Options > Building > Delphi Compiler > Compiling

Use debug .dcus

The debug DCUs contain debug information and are built with stack frames. When this option is checked, the compiler adds the debug DCU path to the search paths specified in Debug Source Path on the Embarcadero Debuggers page.

With a simple C++Builder VCL app with only a button onClick event handler (Button1->Caption = "Clicked";) trace into (F7) into the Caption assignment will only get you to ustring.cpp source code with the "use debug .dcus" set to false and then come back to your C++ source code.

If you "use debug .dcus" set to true, trace into (F7) the Caption assignment will get you to ustring.cpp source code and if you keep tracing into F7 the debugger will continue into Pascal source code in the RTL.

Comment: The documentation is clear about how to set that for the Delphi side. However it is sloppy as ever because it does not mention that this also applies to the C++ side. Delphi has a really tiny community so better documentation would help. The documentation was this way since.... hmmmm.... forever.... No wonder Delphi "sky rocketed" down in Tiobe index from  pos 18 to 30 in only few months! I love Delphi but I don't want to be the last Delphi programmer on the planet. At this moment there are 30 Delphi jobs in the WHOLE Germany. You can find more Colob jobs. Seriously!